# Efficiency formula in Environment-assisted quantum transport (ENAQT)

Tags: quantum-information, density-operator, biophysics, open-quantum-systems, quantum-transport

I'm currently studying the book [quantum effects in biology](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/quantum-effects-in-biology/EE21E9E35A7F0CDC8455118B23762533), in particular, I'm interested in the phenomena of Environment-assisted quantum transport (ENAQT) in photosynthesis.

In ENAQT, they discuss how dephasing can improve the efficiency of a quantum system with disorder. (The original paper is [here](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/11/3/033003/meta), and is open access).

In the book, they define the efficiency of quantum transport by (Chapter 7, section 7.3)

\begin{equation} 
\eta(t) = 2\sum_m\kappa_m \int_0^t \langle m| \rho(t')|m\rangle dt',
\end{equation}
where $\kappa_m$ is a constant, and $\rho(t)$ is the density matrix, which obeys a Linblad equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}\rho(t) = \mathcal{L}[\rho(t)],
\end{equation}
which $\mathcal{L}$ is the Linblad supeoperator, and it is assumed to be independent of time.

My question is the following: In a certain point of section 7.3 of the book, they say (without demonstration) that, for a two-level system, one can rewrite the efficiency as
$$
\eta = - \frac{2}{\hbar}\sum_m \kappa_m \langle m | \mathcal{L}^{-1}\rho(0) | m \rangle. 
$$

How they derive this equation?

I had tried naively to invert the superoperator in the Lindblad equation and assuming that the time derivative commutes with $\mathcal{L}$, giving

$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1}\frac{d}{dt'}\rho(t') =\frac{d}{dt'} \mathcal{L}^{-1}\rho(t') =\rho(t').$$

Thus, I replaced in the definition of the efficiency, giving

$$\eta = 2 \sum_m \kappa_m \mathcal{L}^{-1} \int_0^t \frac{d}{dt'}\langle m| \rho(t')|m\rangle dt'\\ = 2 \sum_m \kappa_m \langle m |(\mathcal{L}^{-1}\rho(t)- \mathcal{L}^{-1}\rho(0))|m\rangle  \\
=  - 2\sum_m \kappa_m \langle m | \mathcal{L}^{-1}\rho(0) | m \rangle  + 2\sum_m \kappa_m \langle m | \mathcal{L}^{-1}\rho(t) | m \rangle. $$

But there is this term depending on $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\rho(t)$, and I don't know how to get rid of this term. Moreover, it seems that there is a missing $\hbar$. What I am missing in this derivation? Should I use another approach?